# Is it better way to avoid „Cannot use mutating member on immutable” in var

Tags: swift

I have a struct with var `grid`

```
struct Machina {
    ....
    var grid: [Whatever] = []
    var other: Something
    ... // other stuff
}
```

But `grid` needs to be counted every time `other` changes. So, I can call

```
var other: Something { 
    didSet {
        defineGrid()
    }
...

mutating func defineGrid() {
    var result: [Whatever] 
    ... // count result
    grid = result
}
```

but I would love to simply call `grid` as **var** and keep counted grid in `_grid`

```
var _grid: [Whatever]? = nil
var other: Something { 
    didSet {
        _grid = nil
    }
...

mutating func defineGrid() {
    var result: [Whatever] 
    ... // count result
    _grid = result
}
...
var grid: [Whatever] {
    if _grid == nil {
        defineGrid() // error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
    }
    return _grid!
}
```

but in this case I got an error. Is a first approach nice? Is it possible to get **var** `grid` from second approach? Maybe it's just a cosmetics. I don't know.

Comment: I don’t get `didChanged { grid = nil }`. It’s not Swift.

Comment: `didSet` of course!

Comment: Also what’s the question? If you don’t like mutating, use a class not a struct.

Comment: By first approach a I can mutate by mutating func. In second I cannot. The question is it is possible to have var `grid` which returns value of _grid or count if it is nil.

Comment: in second approach `_grid` is defined as `[Whatever]?`. I couldn't be `nil`?

Comment: I hope I remove all typos now

Comment: I think you're looking for a `mutating get`

Comment: I never heard about but I think I was looked for. Thank you!

Comment: How about getting rid of this `_grid` and just defining `grid` to be `private(set) var grid: [Whatever] = []`. That makes it mutable within the class, but immutable externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexander said, you need a `mutating` getter for `grid`:

```
var grid: [Whatever] {
    mutating get {
        if _grid == nil {
            defineGrid()
        }
        return _grid!
    }
}
```

Also, `_grid` should probably be `private`.

Comment: Yes, it will be private

Comment: Oh,  that's just `lazy` variable initialisation. Isn't it built in in `Swift` already?

Comment: @user28434 This is not the same as `lazy`. `grid` lazily _changes_ with `other`. If you use `lazy` it won't change as `other` changes.

Comment: @Sweeper, yeah, `lazy` with `reset` feature. Can be implemented with `@propertyWrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

If `Swift 5` is used you can also use this handy `@propertyWrapper`:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct LazyWithReset<T> {
    private var value: T? = nil // this is hidden storage for the value, like _grid in the question

    var wrappedValue: T { // this is lazy-ish interface to access/generate value, like grid in the question
        mutating get {
            if (value == nil) {
                value = generator()
            }
            return value!
        }
    }
    var generator: () -> T // this is the function that sets value, like defineGrid in the question

    init(_ generator: @escaping () -> T) {
        self.generator = generator
    }

    mutating func reset() { // this is just resetting the storage while keeping internals hidden
        value = nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Machina {
    @LazyWithReset(defineGrid)
    private(set) var grid: [Whatever] // no initial value required, generator will lazily provide value if needed

    var other: Something {
        didSet {
            _grid.reset() // variable set, we reset our lazy variable
        }
    }

    private static func defineGrid() -> [Whatever] { // now it's pure static function, no mutability required
        return … // whatever you was directly setting to the grid var previously
    }
}
```

This way you can hide all boilerplate code under the rug and keep your business logic clean.

Also `LazyWithReset<T>` can be reused wherever you want, so you won't have to copy-paste any code.

Comment: Oh! It looks very smart. I will read about @propertyWrappers. Thank you